# Javascript Async/Await not returning, more like Await_Forever

Tags: javascript

I started started a node environment based off express, my issue is more with `Promise`.
I've written a module that has an http call (axios) and i'm using async/await in order to receive the response and handle it, everything is working great in the module in terms of flow and i'm able to execute `console.log()`s, yet my returned value isn't coming back to `index.js`.

#### index.js

works great and my `readFile()` function works great.

```
const getDistance = require('./actions/getDistance');
    app.post('/find-closest', async (req, res) =>{
        try{
            let address = req.body.address;
            let data = await readFile('src/agents.json');
            return res.json(getDistance(JSON.parse(data),address));
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error');
            console.log(e);
            return res.json(e);
        }
    });
```

#### getDistance.js

```
module.exports = function (agents, origins) {
    let destinations = '&destinations=' + agents.map(agent => agent.address).join('|');

    const getDistances = async () => {
        try {
            return await axios.get(url + origins + destinations + apiKey)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
        }
    };

    const setDistancesResponse = async () => {
        const distances = await getDistances()

        console.log('test',distances.data); //<=this returns
        return 'baboom'; //this is not returned through
    };
    setDistancesResponse();
};
```

I am expecting my endpoint to return a JSON response of the string "baboom".

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks, Bud

Comment: Have you checked the Network tab to ensure that you have successfully made the request?

Comment: yes, I'm getting 200

Comment: the top level function is not returning anything. Did you mean `return setDistancesResponse()`?

Comment: How do you know `setDistancesResponse();` does not return 'baboom' when you don't return or save the result of `setDistancesResponse();`? I would expect like `return setDistancesResponse();` or `const response = await setDistancesResponse(); return response;`.

Comment: don't use `return await axios.get(url + origins + destinations + apiKey)` - instead await the promise in a variable assignment. a.e. `let response = await axios.get(url + origins + destinations + apiKey); return response;`

Comment: Why do you even have those many nested functions in getDistance?

Comment: @zfrisch Those two seem pretty equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exported `getDistance` function doesn't `return` anything. You are probably looking for

```
module.exports = async function(agents, origins) {
    const destinations = '&destinations=' + agents.map(agent => agent.address).join('|');
    const distances = await axios.get(url + origins + destinations + apiKey)
    console.log('test',distances.data); // this logs something
    return 'baboom';
};
```

and given that this now returns a promise, you will have to wait for the result value:

```
app.post('/find-closest', async (req, res) =>{
    try{
        let address = req.body.address;
        let data = await readFile('src/agents.json');
        return res.json(await getDistance(JSON.parse(data), address));
//                      ^^^^^
    } catch (e) {
        console.error('Error', e);
        return res.json(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: hotdamn, Thanks Bergi.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misses return value. Try this:

```
return setDistancesResponse();
```

Comment: well at least now i'm receiving an empty object, but not the string at the end of `setDistancesResponse()`